# What is the correct method used to encrypt the SOAP header?

Tags: .net

I know that the SOAP Header is used to transmit auxiliary information relevant to the Web Service processing that isn't part of the method signature.I want to know how to encrypt SOAP message header.

Answer (score 0):

What is your aim in this? If you are looking for a secure SOAP connection then rather than encrypting each part why not just run the whole thing over HTTPS?